# Why am I getting "Cannot draw recycled bitmaps"?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am taking a bitmap, creating a new one from the original and then setting the new one to an `ImageView`, when I recycle the original I get that error, but I am not drawing the original? For more detail read my comments in my code. As you can see I recycle the bitmap that comes in which I do not draw, I always make a new bitmap called tile that I draw.

My Code:

```
public void tileImage(Bitmap bm){
    if(bm==null){
        Debug.out("Bitmap is null");
    }
    else{
         Bitmap tile;
         float tileWidth = bm.getWidth();
         float tileHeight =1024;
 //if my bitmap is too wide
         if(bm.getWidth()>width){
             Debug.out("Bitmap too wide: "+bm.getWidth());
 //if this code runs I get no error, if not I get the error
             bm =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,
                (int)width,
                (int)(bm.getHeight()*(float)(width/tileWidth)),
                false
                );
           }
         Debug.out("Bitmap height: "+bm.getHeight()+" adjusted width "+bm.getWidth());
 //if my bitmap is too tall
         if(bm.getHeight()>tileHeight){
              for(int i = 0; tileHeight*i<bm.getHeight(); i++){
                   image = new ImageView(main);
 //make tiles of the body
                    if((tileHeight*(i+1))<bm.getHeight()){
                         tile = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                bm,
                                0, 
                                (int)(tileHeight*i),
                                (int)bm.getWidth(),
                                (int)(tileHeight)
                           );
                           Debug.out("Tiling: "+i);
                       }
 //tile the reaminder
                     else{
                           tile = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                               bm,
                               0, 
                               (int)(tileHeight*i),
                               (int)bm.getWidth(),
                               (int)(bm.getHeight()%tileHeight)
                          );
                           Debug.out("Tiling: "+bm.getHeight()%tileHeight+" "+i);
                     }  
                image.setImageBitmap(tile);
                tiles.addView(image);               
           }
         }
 //else its not too tall
    else{
        image = new ImageView(main);

        Debug.out("No tiling");

        tile = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                 bm,
                 0, 
                 0,
                 (int)bm.getWidth(),
                 (int)bm.getHeight()
                 );
        Debug.out("Bitmap too small height: "+bm.getHeight()+" width "+bm.getWidth());
            image.setImageBitmap(tile);
        tiles.addView(image); 

    }

  }
 //this is the trouble maker
bm.recycle();
}
```

Comment: have you used the bitmap after call of titleimage method

Comment: no what you see is it

Comment: usually this happens when you use after recycle.. but in your case not sure what is happening

Comment: does the fact that if I reassign the var, like I do when the bitmap is too wide, give a clue, because in bitmaps that trigger that if block do not result in the error... same bitmap and everything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218976/cannot-draw-recycled-bitmaps-when-displaying-bitmaps-in-gallery-attached-to-ad .. check whether it can help you a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Bitmap.createBitmap(params) Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may have been made.
- bitmap.recycle() method Frees the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the reference to the pixel data. This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more references to this bitmap.
- onDraw() method takes some time to inflate the View. If you are passing the bitmap to draw a view and calling recycle() on the same reference then the bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and will draw nothing.
- You should call recycle() in onDestroy().

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        image1.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        tileImage();
    }

    private void tileImage() {
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0,
            (int) mBitmap.getWidth(), (int) mBitmap.getHeight());
        image2.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mBitmap.recycle();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt know it could return the same bitmap..that seems like it might be my issue as I often try to make a new bitmap of the same height and width as the old....I do this so I can recycle the old..

Comment: mBitmap.recycle() is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more references to this bitmap.

Comment: it's not really an advanced call. when you no longer need a bitmap, you should call recycle on it. simple. in fact, the official documentation recommends you to use the recycle call on API levels < 11 because of the way the GC works there. calling recycle before waiting for onDestroy can prevent OOM errros. see http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is not entirely correct. You should in fact not wait until onDestroy with recycle. Especially if you make heavy use of creating these bitmaps. You might not even get to onDestroy before you get an OOM error. What you should do is test the dimensions you're scaling it to to the dimensions of the bitmap. If they are equal, return the original bitmap and no recycle is necessary. Otherwise, you'll get a new bitmap object and you should immediately call recyle on the original bitmap.

see http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html